# getaddrinfo "10 . 10 . 10 . 10"

Tags: linux, macos, sockets

I just noticed that if I feed the string "10 . 10 . 10 . 10" to getaddrinfo i get back the address 0.0.0.10. The result is the same on both OS X (Lion) and Linux (CentOS 5.6). You can easily verify it yourself with:

```
$ curl 'http://10 . 10 . 10 . 10/' 
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.10: No route to host
```

Is there a specific reason for this behavior or should I consider it a bug? I would've expected it to fail to return any address.

Edit: Same result for "10 asdf", guess it's the space that makes it do that.

Comment: I use getaddrinfo to verify that a valid address was entered into a field, instead of using a regex which is prone to not do a good match (especially for IPv6).

Comment: But why would you even allow spaces to form part of the address in the first place ?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm asking isn't it. Why does getaddrinfo allow it? I added my own check for whitespace before calling getaddrinfo now, but I still think the behavior is weird, and want to know if it's explicit or accidental.

Comment: You said that you are passing "10 . 10 . 10 . 10" *to* `getaddrinfo` - where did the spaces comes from ?

Comment: From a user input field in my application.

Comment: OK - so to repeat my earlier question, why do you even *allow* spaces to form part of the address in the first place, i.e. why do you allow the user to enter spaces in an IP address field ?

Comment: Sure, I could write some javascript to prevent it. But I figured that using getaddrinfo was the most simple way to verify the address. I don't think that's a very strange way to do it.

Comment: (and that's if I discard the fact that I'm not the guy in charge of that part of the interface)

Comment: Sorry, but this is one of my pet peeves - interfaces that allow you to enter what they consider to be invalid input and then don't complain until you hit "submit" - the worst offender is credit card number entry fields (why allow spaces if you don't want them ? or why not quietly strip them out afterwards ? sheesh...), and it sounds like your IP address entry field suffers from the same poor design.

Comment: Well, as much as I'd love to have that discussion (which is not as black or white as you seem to believe), this is not the right place for it. As far as you know, this could very well be the ajax enabled code that's run before submit is hit (ok it isn't, but it could've been).

Comment: OK - well if your GUI code is flaky and can't be fixed then you'll just have to take additional precautions with the unfiltered field values that you get (like stripping out spaces and other garbage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) allows a string consisting of a single number (in either decimal, hex with a leading `0x` or `0X`, or octal with a leading `0`) to specify an IPv4 address: see the definition of [`inet_addr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_addr.html) (referenced by the definition of [`getaddrinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html) for the `AF_INET` address family).

As far as I can see, it doesn't say anything about how the input string is terminated, so the fact that it stops at a space is probably just an implementation detail; but "10" is certainly an allowable representation of an IPv4 address, if it's parsed by `getaddrinfo()` or `inet_addr()`.  (Interestingly, this form is *not* allowed by [`inet_pton()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_pton.html) with `AF_INET` - that only accepts the standard four-component form.)

Comment: Yeah, I've realized this can't really be answered better than this. I suppose it is a bit of an open question.